# Angular 10 - Does Angular have a way to build paths of routes for you?

Tags: angular, angular-router

You can attach data to a route like this:

```
// app-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: "/some/path/bla/", component: SomeComponent, data:{ name: "home1"}},  
  {path: "/some/path/:variable/bla/", component: SomeComponent, data:{ name: "home2"}},
]
```

Does Angular's Router module have an in-built way to generate the path for you from that data, such as this:

```
const routeName1 = "home1";
getPathForRoute(routeName1) //Returns "/some/path/bla/"

const routeName2 = "home2";
const parameters = {"variable": "stringValueForVariable"};
getPathForRoute(routeName2, parameters); //Returns "/some/path/stringValueForVariable/bla/"
```

This is purely to avoid hard-coding paths/routes, similar to how you can do so in Django with its `reverse` function. I'm aware that the default suggestion seems to be to just throw your routes in a module full of constants and refer to that instead. However, that seems like an unclean solution to me given that you need to maintain that constants file.

This concept seems easy to implement and given that I know there are a lot of smart people working on this, I am almost certain this functionality is in there somewhere and I just don't recognize it. However, skimming through [angular's routing documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#using-relative-paths), nothing stands out to be Angular's version of this kind of functionality. SO-Questions about avoiding hard-coding routes mostly get answered with aforementioned solution of having a constants-file to store the urls in, which I'd like to avoid for the mentioned reasons. So what am I missing?

Edit: I have accepted that apparently Angular doesn't have anything for this. As such, if anyone wants to go about implementing it themselves, here is what I did so far if you want inspiration (and by the time you're reading this hopefully with a code-review below it to improve whatever I implemented):
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/253189/implementing-djangos-reverse-functionality-in-angular-routing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge, Angular Router module doesn't have any in-built way to generate the path. you have to declare the path in routing modules and in code you can use the below code to redirect to the particular page

```
this.router.navigate(['/custompath']);
```

Comment: Heya, thanks for the response. So there is no way to avoid hard-coding your path, is there? Since even `'/custompath'` means hard-coding your path again, correct?
Seems like a reasonable thing to me to just grab all routes from router.config, filter for the one you care about through the data attribute and then write a function that replaces variables in your paths with values, if there are any. If no contrary feedback arrives in the next 24h I'll mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: As stated before I accept this answer. This does require a sidenote however since, as @avinashkr pointed out in his answer, there is the function `createUrlTree`. It does however not seems to be resistant to minor URL changes the same way Django's reverse is, so effectively it offers no benefits in my eyes, making this answer overall still the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by using createUrlTree :

```
this.router.createUrlTree(['home2', 'book', 'details', id])
```

You can get the complete url(https://*) by using the router methods below:

```
this.router.serializeUrl(
  this.router.createUrlTree(['home2', 'book', 'details', id])
);
```

*Note : id is url params;

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So the entire URL is interpreted as a tree with segments, and then generated by sticking the segments together?I like this better than what I've found so far, but I don't think it's stable to if I were to change the route-path, is it? Say I change `/home2/book/details/1` to `/home3/book/details/1` or `/home2/files/book/details/1`, I'd need to adjust the `string[]`-parameter in `createUrlTree`, correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct. You would have to update that segment.